# I can't install intel HAXM on my computer

Tags: android, intel

Please help me to install HAXM.When i try to install HAXM, the system enconters an error.That is 
This computer meets the requirements for HAXM,but intel virtualuzation technology(VT-x) is not turned on.HAXM cannot be installed untill VT-x is enabled.
This is the error message.
but i go to my boot menu and make sure intel vertualuzation technology is enabled.Then i reinstall HAXM but again the same error.
Please advise me to remove the problem.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Answer (score 4):

**When**

```
Error 1714. 
The older version of Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager cannot be removed. 
Contact your technical support group. 
System Error 1612.
```

[1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKSXz.png

**Then**

In REGEDIT go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\
and Search for 'HAXM' then you will find it under a key in sourcelist as in

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\05...0\SourceList\

Delete that entire registry entry (you may want to export it and save it if timid)
Then just reinstall it (eg  inside Android Studio or https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_3_0.zip - which begs the question if it would not uninstall 6.2.1 how hard would it be to have had a previous version such as the illusive https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v6_2_1.zip ?)

**Result**

```
Android SDK is up to date.

Running Intel® HAXM installer

Intel HAXM updated successfully!

Done
```

re:https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Comment: Excellent solution

Answer (score 0):

Press windows key logo + x. This will launch the list of options - select program and features -> Turn Off windows feature. Uncheck the Hyper-V.

Then restart your system.